# The variable name '@days' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

i want to store multiple selected values of checkboxlist in sql server. when i select one value it goes into database but when selected multiple it gives above error.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IvrContext"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Ivrdatas (days) values (@days)", conn);
        string empty = "";
        foreach (ListItem lst in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (lst.Selected == true)
            {
                empty = empty + " " + lst.Value;
                com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@days", empty);
                     com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        } 
        conn.Close();



    }
```

here is my html.

```
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 299px" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Monday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Tuesday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Wednesday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Thursday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Friday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Saturday</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Sunday</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: Somebody please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to save multiple values then you first build the string you want to save and when your for each is ready add it.

And also open the connection on the last moment and don't forget to dispose the command.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IvrContext"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Ivrdatas (days) values (@days)", conn);
    string empty = "";
    foreach (ListItem lst in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (lst.Selected == true)
        {
            empty = empty + " " + lst.Value;
        }
    } 
    com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@days", empty);
    conn.Open();
    com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    com1.Dispose();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i entered insert query inside loop and it solved the problem. Thanks every one for suggesting answers!

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IvrContext"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string empty = "";
        foreach (ListItem lst in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (lst.Selected == true)
            {

                empty = lst.Value;
                SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT into Ivrdatas (days) values ('" + empty + "')", conn);

                     com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```